# Why would str_replace not replace question marks?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string with question marks ('?') in it and I want to replace it with something parsable.

However str_replace will not replace any ? characters in my string...

```
$str = str_replace('?', 'replacement', $str);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

That code does replace question marks with the word replacement, which means that's not the code you're using, or what's in your string is not a question mark.

PHP's string functions only operate correctly on latin1 (iso-8859-1) encoded strings. In many encodings there may be many codepoints that correspond to a glyph that looks like a question mark visually, but is not the same as ASCII ?.

---

```
$str = "Hello? Anyone home?";
$str = str_replace('?', 'replacement', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

> Helloreplacement Anyone homereplacement

Comment: +1 for good reasoning + support. Encoding seems to be the likely culprit here.

Comment: I found my problem.  My string has some special characters (hex value 80 and 0x93).  How do I cleanse my string of these special chars?

Comment: What makes them special? What do you want to do with them? What if your 'cleansing' changes the meaning of the text?

Answer (score 0):

This will replace `?` in to `space`. This may help you.

```
<?php
$str = "this ? does ? indeed ? work";
$char='';
$str1 = str_replace('?',$char,$str);
echo $str1;
?>
```